# Intersect two traversals in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to understand how to intersect two results in ArangoDB and my scenario looks like this.

[image: Example]

I can easily find users living in Spain, Island or Europe with the query:

```
FOR x IN 1..3 INBOUND "places/Europe" situedIn,livesIn 
FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('users',x)
return x
```

What I want to understand is the best way to extend the search capabilities to include Profession:

Example:

- Return all Police in Spain (returns [A])
- Return all Police in Europe (returns [A])
- Return all Legal in Europe (returns [A,B])

Thankful for any help

Answer (score 3):

After some more searching the answer is INTERSECTION

```
FOR a IN INTERSECTION (

(FOR x IN 1..3 INBOUND "places/Europe" situedIn
   FOR p IN INBOUND x livesIn
   return p),

(FOR x IN 1..3 INBOUND "profession/Medical" specializes
   FOR p IN INBOUND x worksWith
   return p)

) RETURN a
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_commonNeighbors` function may be what you're looking for. It returns the intersection between two sets of vertices.

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/graphs/general-graphs/functions/#_commonneighbors

Comment: Thanks. How would that be different from the below solution?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what's happening under the hood, but I believe it is an optimized algorithm that minimizes the traversal required to perform the search.